# Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A\x0AC…' for column 'text_body' at row 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to store email content in mysql.

But i'm facing errors while trying to insert the row.

I have done some research and changed the column type to utf8mb4. But I'm still facing the problem.

Can someone tell me what i'm missing?

This is the error I'm getting

`Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A\x0AC...' for column 'text_body' at row 1`

This is the character set of my table `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429481/470749 helped me with my database and table encodings for emojis.

Answer (score 11):

The `CHARACTER SET` of the *column* needs to be utf8mb4.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for confirmation.

Also, the connection needs to be utf8mb4 (or `UTF-8`, depending on the client language).  Let's see the connection parameters.